# Recursive linkscraper c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm struggling with this a whole day now and I can't seem to figure it out.
I have a fucntion that gives me a list of all links on a specific url. That works fine.
However I want to make this function recursive so that it searches for the links found with the first search and adds them to the list and continue so that it goes through all my pages on the website.
How can I make this recursive?

My code:

```
class Program
{
public static List<LinkItem> urls;
private static List<LinkItem> newUrls = new List<LinkItem>();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  WebClient w = new WebClient();
  int count = 0;
  urls = new List<LinkItem>();
  newUrls = new List<LinkItem>();
  urls.Add(new LinkItem{Href = "http://www.smartphoto.be", Text = ""});

  while (urls.Count > 0)
  {
    foreach (var url in urls)
    {
      if (RemoteFileExists(url.Href))
      {
        string s = w.DownloadString(url.Href);
        newUrls.AddRange(LinkFinder.Find(s));
      }
    }
    urls = newUrls.Select(x => new LinkItem{Href = x.Href, Text=""}).ToList();
    count += newUrls.Count;
    newUrls.Clear();
    ReturnLinks();
  }

  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.Write("Found: " + count + " links.");
  Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void ReturnLinks()
{
  foreach (LinkItem i in urls)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(i.Href);
    //ReturnLinks();
  }
}

private static bool RemoteFileExists(string url)
{
  try
  {
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "HEAD";
    //Getting the Web Response.
    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    //Returns TURE if the Status code == 200
    return (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
  }
  catch
  {
    return false;
  }
}
}
```

The code behind LinkFinder.Find can be found here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/scraping-html

Anyone knows how I can either make that function recursive or can I make the ReturnLinks function recursive? I prefer to not touch the LinkFinder.Find method as this works perfect for one link, I just should be able to call it as many times as needed to expand my final url list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to load each link and find the link within, and continue until you run out of links?

Since it is likely that the recursion depth could get very large, i would avoid recursion, this should work i think.

```
WebClient w = new WebClient();
int count = 0;    
urls = new List<string>();
newUrls = new List<LinkItem>();
urls.Add("http://www.google.be"); 

while (urls.Count > 0)
{
    foreach(var url in urls)
    {
        string s = w.DownloadString(url);
        newUrls.AddRange(LinkFinder.Find(s));
    }
    urls = newUrls.Select(x=>x.Href).ToList();
    count += newUrls.Count;
    newUrls.Clear();
    ReturnLinks();
}

Console.WriteLine();
Console.Write("Found: " + count + " links.");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thx for your quick reply! However it doesn't work :( When I clear the newUrls nothing is shown, which is correct because urls=newUrls. When I remove the newUrls.clear, I get a collection modified error on line urls = newUrls...

Comment: @Stieven76, yeah you're right, i edited a bit to just extract the hrefs as a list of string which i think should work, otherwise you could simply do it with a normal for loop and append to the list on the fly.

Comment: I have modified it a little bit and now it does seem to work. However now i've encoutered an other problem. One of the found links throws a 404 error on this line in the loop: string s = w.DownloadString(url); Which is correct as the page is not available. How can i skip a link that throws an error? Thx a lot for your help so far!!

Comment: K, I was able to overcome the 404 error by first checking if the page exists. Not there yet, now I've encountered the problem I was afraid of from the beginning. The progam is in a infinite loop as it keeps finding links because each page is connected to eachother. It doesn't add the links double to the list because I check if the link is already in the List before adding it, but it keeps searching. Breaking my head around this to let the program exit the search loop when there are no more links to add.. I'll update my original post with the new code!

Comment: I have put the project I currently have on my space. Maybe you could download it from there and take a look, then you'll see what the problem is. Do you have Fiddler? Then you can see the program still downloading links even when no output is generated. [Link](http://users.telenet.be/pit/)  ConsoleAppLinksraper.rar

Comment: @Stieven76, it seems fine to me it's just that the output is done in batches and due to the nature of the algorithm the batches increase in size expoenentially so therefore the wait time between outputs also increases. Also the ReturnLink function is output all links each time so there is repetition, i recomomend changing the function to output a single link taken as a parameter and calling it each time.

Comment: I have started the progam before I went to bed and when I got up it still wasn't finished although I didn't see anything move anymore.
I removed the ReturnLinks part and printed every link directly when it was being processed. I'll update the project rar so you could check if your interessed. Something isn't still quite right. I didn't expect something so simple being so hard actually :)

Comment: I finally found it. Now it works as I would expect :) Thx for pointing me the way!

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main()
{
    WebClient w = new WebClient();

    List<ListItem> allUrls = FindAll(w.DownloadString("http://www.google.be"));
}

private static List<ListItem> FindAll(string address)
{
    List<ListItem> list = new List<ListItem>();

    foreach (url in LinkFinder.Find(address))
    {
        list.AddRange(FindAll(url.Address)));//or url.ToString() or what ever the string that represents the address
    }

    return list;
}
```